# Magento2: How to show product URL on Homepage

Tags: magento2, category-products, product-urls, home-page

I have to show list of product on same category on homepage

I have achieved the same using **CatalogWidget** but got issue with URL,
It shows URL like **example.net/product** but I want to show URL like **example.net/category/product**  on homepage

how can I achieve the same

Comment: Have you tried this? go to Store -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimization -> "Use Categories Path for Product URLs" set to "Yes"

Comment: This works on list page well. I need to show complete URL on homepage

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code in your template file for getting the URL with category only on the page you want.

```
<?php 
    $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
    $cats = $_item->getCategoryIds();
        if(count($cats) ){

            if($cats[0]==2){
                $firstCategoryId = $cats[1];
            }
            else{
                $firstCategoryId = $cats[0];
            }

        $_category = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($firstCategoryId);
        $categorykey = $_category->getUrlKey();
        $siteurl = $block->getUrl('*/*/*', ['_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true]);      
        $productUrl = $siteurl.$categorykey."/".$_item->getUrlKey().".html";
    }
    else{
        $productUrl = $block->getProductUrl($_item);
    }
?>
```

However, the use of the `$objectManager` is not recommended in the template file directly. You can use the dependency injection in your block class for the same.

**Hope it helps!!!**